# Closed form expression of a recursive relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

Consider the function $f \colon (0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \colon x \mapsto 1/2(1 - e^{-1/x})$. Consider the recursive relation
$$
\left \{
\begin{array}{ll}
g_0(x) = f(x) & \\
g_k(x) = g_{0}(g_{k - 1}(x)) & \forall k \geq 1
\end{array}
\right .
$$
I would like to find a closed form for the function $g_k(x)$. Alternatively, it would be interesting to understand the asymmtotic behavious of the functions $g_k(x)$, i.e. find
$$
\lim_{x\to + \infty} g_k(x)
$$

Comment: I don't think there is any hope for a closed-form. Where is the question coming from ?

Comment: This is just a calculation that popped up in my work.

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Lie.27s_data_transport_equation

But it might be hard to calculate the derivative and would only give you an operator to apply to the function. This leads onto https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator

Comment: have you tried graphing the first few iterations to get a sense of how this evolves

Comment: I only breifly tried with Wolfram. For $k = 0$ the limit of $g_k$ is $0$; for k = 1 the limit is $1/2$; for k = 2 it is $(e^2 - 1)/(2 e^2)$. I would expect these limits to always be in range $[0, 1]$, and possibly to approach $1$ as $k$ increases.

Comment: looks like 0.6275ish constant?

Comment: The fixed point of $f_k$ is $x\approx0.4466986177721$. This is the value of $f_\infty(\infty)$. The second iterate is pretty flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first iterate is asymptotic to

$$\frac1{2x},$$ which obviously tends to zero.

The second iterate is thus asymptotic to

$$\frac{1-e^{-2x}}2$$ and quickly tends to $\dfrac 12$.

Hence the next iterates are virtually constant and equal to the iterates from $\dfrac12$, which linearly tend to the fixed point, solution of

$$\frac{1-e^{-1/x}}2=x.$$

Notice that the iterates starting from $x=0$ are $\dfrac12$, then $f\left(\dfrac12\right)\cdots$ so that except for the first, all iterates are very flat and vary only in the interval between terms iterated from $0$.

---

An engineer would say "$g_k(x)$ is $0.45$".